# ¿Por qué la tercera línea no es procesada?

Tags: c++

En el archivo `entrada.txt` tengo:

```
Linea numero uno
Linea numero dos
Linea numero tres
```

Y en el archivo `salida.txt` obtengo tras la ejecución:

```
Linea numero uno
Linea numero dos
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
    string linea;  string tmp;
    ofstream salida; salida.open ("salida.txt");
    ifstream archivo; archivo.open ("entrada.txt");

    while(!getline(archivo, linea).eof()) {
            linea += '\n';
            unique_copy (linea.begin(), linea.end(), back_inserter(tmp), [](char c1, char c2){ return c1 == ' ' && c2 == ' '; }); }

    salida <<  tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no es procesada la tercera línea? ¿Podrías indicar sistema operativo en el que estás haciendo las pruebas y el formato de texto (tipo de retorno del carro) que tiene `entrada.txt`? He probado con el contenido en base64 `TGluZWEgbnVtZXJvIHVubw0KTGluZWEgbnVtZXJvIGRvcw0KTGluZWEgbnVtZXJvIHRyZXMNCg==` y funciona correctamente.

Comment: He conseguido reproducir tu problema con `TGluZWEgbnVtZXJvIHVubwpMaW5lYSBudW1lcm8gZG9zCkxpbmVhIG51bWVybyB0cmVz`. Es decir, sin el último `\n` al final de la tercera línea. Redactando posible solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu bucle while puedes tener dos casos cuando obtienes la última línea:

- Contiene el delimitador al final (`texto\n<eof>`): obtienes `texto` en `linea` y **no se activa** la bandera  [`eofbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).
- No contiene delimitador (`texto<eof>`): obtienes `texto` en `linea` y **sí se activa** la bandera  [`eofbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).

En el primer caso la siguiente iteración de tu bucle obtiene una línea adicional vacía, pero como se activa la bandera `eofbit` sale del bucle y finaliza la ejecución.

En el segundo caso la línea obtenida no se trata porque la bandera `eofbit` se había activado, por lo finaliza tu bucle sin tratar su contenido.

Mi recomendación es que compruebes el estado de la bandera `eofbit` **después** de haber tratado la línea leída. En caso de ser la última línea sin delimitador `\n`, la variable `linea` estará vacía, pero podemos evitar enviar el delimitador al destino si no lo tenía el origen comprobando el estado de la bandera `eofbit`.

Una implementación podría ser la siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
    std::string linea, tmp;
    std::ofstream salida;
    std::ifstream archivo;

    salida.open ("salida.txt");
    archivo.open ("entrada.txt");

    do {
        /* Tratamos de leer la siguiente línea, si no hay más devuelve
            una cadena vacía */
        getline(archivo, linea);
        /* Evitamos agregar un carácter "\n" adicional en archivos que
            no terminen originalmente con él */
        if (!archivo.eof()) {
            linea += '\n';
        }
        std::unique_copy(
            linea.begin(), 
            linea.end(),
            std::back_inserter(tmp),
            [](char c1, char c2) { return c1 == ' ' && c2 == ' '; }
        );
    } while(!archivo.eof());
    /* Volcamos en salida el contenido de tmp */
    salida << tmp;
    return 0;
}
```

Versión "con menos código":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    std::string linea, tmp; std::ofstream salida; std::ifstream archivo;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES"); salida.open ("salida.txt"); archivo.open ("entrada.txt");

    do { getline(archivo, linea); if (!archivo.eof()) linea += '\n';
    std::unique_copy(linea.begin(), linea.end(), std::back_inserter(tmp), [](char c1, char c2) { return c1 == ' ' && c2 == ' '; });
    } while(!archivo.eof()); salida << tmp;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: funciona...   pero... mucho código... no puede resumirse más... ?

Comment: Sólo he agregado un `if` para evitar el último retorno del carro, cambiado el `while() {}` por un `do {} while()`, dividida la línea del `std::unique_copy` en varias líneas para facilitar su lectura y separadas en dos líneas algunas instrucciones que estaban en una única. Puedes quitar el `if` si no lo necesitas. El resto que engorda el código son comentarios explicando lo que hago.

Comment: Sin el IF... también funciona....

Comment: do {
        getline(archivo, linea);
        linea += '\n';
        unique_copy (linea.begin(),linea.end(), back_inserter(tmp), [](char c1, char c2) { return c1 == ' ' && c2 == ' '; } );
    } while (! archivo.eof ());

Answer (score 0):

Sin el IF, también funciona:

```
do {
    getline(archivo, linea);
    linea += '\n';
    unique_copy (linea.begin(),linea.end(), back_inserter(tmp), [](char c1, char c2) { return c1 == ' ' && c2 == ' '; } );
} while (! archivo.eof ());
```

Comment: GETLINE toma la línea y también se activa el indicador de EOF que obliga a salir del bucle.